# CSS Keyframes Hover Animation Not Working In Chrome

Tags: hover, webkit, css-animations, rotatetransform

I recently migrated my website and somewhat simple CSS hover animation stopped working in chrome.

Animations work in IE and firefox.

the animation I am referring to can be seen at:
http://a1decals.com/products-page/tech-stuff-decals/coexist-decal-sticker-operating-systems/

If you click on an image in the product gallery, it will popup to full size, then an animation takes effect while hovering.

I have a bunch of CSS animations going on without any problems and this used to work on another host.

```
.highslide-wrapper,
.highslide-outline,
.highslide-wrapper:hover,
.highslide-outline:hover {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
z-index: 99999999 !important;
}
.highslide-image {
z-index: 99999999 !important;
border-style: solid !important;
border-color: #1a00ff !important;
border: 12px solid rgb(16, 0, 240) !important;
padding: 15px !important;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px !important;
-moz-border-radius: 10px !important;
border-radius: 10px !important;
}
.highslide-image:hover {
cursor: crosshair;
z-index: 99999999 !important;
-webkit-animation-name: rotateA;
-webkit-animation-duration: 12s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
-moz-animation-name: rotateA;
-moz-animation-duration: 12s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-moz-transition-timing-function: linear;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-ms-animation-name: rotateA;
-ms-animation-duration: 12s;
-ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-ms-transition-timing-function: linear;
animation-name: rotateA;
animation-duration: 12s;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
transition-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes rotateA { 
35% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    transform: rotate(0deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(-30deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    transform: rotate(-30deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-75deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-75deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(-75deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-75deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    transform: rotate(-75deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
55% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-350deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-350deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(-350deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-350deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    transform: rotate(-350deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
}
60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    background-color: rgba(212, 36, 36, 0.8);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    background-color: rgba(212, 36, 36, 0.8);
}
}
```

tried clearing browser cookies, tried different computers and webkit phone browsers.
At my old host everything worked fine on all browsers, and this is a backup copy migrated to a new server.

i tried deactivating most all plugins, i tried removing a content type header tag.
i tried inserting css for the non hover state with
transform: rotate(0deg)
and transform:scale(1)

i tried changing the position of the image class and the container class to

```
position: relative  !important;
```

instead of absolute.

i inspected the elements to look for anything blocking the mouse hover.

since this is new hosting from siteground.com, they have a great wordpress enviornment for shared hosting compared to hostgator.com maybe it has something to do with the hosting enviornment so i had a ticket with this issue addressed and they confirmed the problem and after checking they couldnt pinpoint a problem, they also pointed me to an article that didnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the animation coding.

i didnt declare the @-webkit-keyframes rotateA part, only wrote the lines that make it up.
whats strange is this worked on phones and pcs for a long time and just stopped recently.

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotateA { 
35% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
-o-transform: rotate(0deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
-ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
transform: rotate(0deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
40% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
-moz-transform: rotate(-30deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
-o-transform: rotate(-30deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
-ms-transform: rotate(-30deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
transform: rotate(-30deg) scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-75deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
-moz-transform: rotate(-75deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
-o-transform: rotate(-75deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
-ms-transform: rotate(-75deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
transform: rotate(-75deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
55% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-350deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
-moz-transform: rotate(-350deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
-o-transform: rotate(-350deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
-ms-transform: rotate(-350deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
transform: rotate(-350deg) scaleX(-1.2) scaleY(1.2) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
}
60% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
-moz-transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
-o-transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
-ms-transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
background-color: rgba(212, 36, 36, 0.8);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
-moz-transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
-o-transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
-ms-transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
transform: rotate(-360deg) scaleX(-1.0) scaleY(1.0) skew(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
background-color: rgba(212, 36, 36, 0.8);
}
}
```